# How can you construct a dictionary from lists of keys and data?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have 3 lists as below:

```
names = ["paul", "saul", "steve", "chimpy"]
ages = [28, 59, 22, 5]
scores = [59, 85, 55, 60]
```

And I need to convert them to a dictionary like this:

```
{'steve': [22, 55, 'fail'], 'saul': [59, 85, 'pass'], 'paul': [28, 59, 'fail'], 'chimpy': [5, 60, 'pass']}
```

'pass' and 'fail' are coming from the score if it is >=60 or not.

I can do this with a series of `for loops` but I'm looking for more neat/professional method.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your current solution.  Also, the Code Review site is more appropriate for questions about how to improve code.

Comment: Hint: have a look at python's `zip()` function.

Comment: You don't need a series of loops. Look at the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: `zip` doesn't produce a dictionary, but it organizes the contents of the lists to make doing so pretty straight-forward w/o needing a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zip you can do at least this "condensed" implementation:

```
res = dict()
for n,a,s in zip(names,ages,scores):
   res[n] = [a,s,'fail' if s <60 else 'pass']
```

Comment: You can take this a step further and eliminate the need for any loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very neatly using [dictionary comprehension](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-dictionary-comprehension):

```
D = {name: [score, age, 'fail' if score<60 else 'pass'] for name, score, age in zip(names, scores, ages)}
```